# "structure of query does not match function result type. Returned type double precision does not match expected type integer in column 1."?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

> ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type DETAIL:
>   Returned type double precision does not match expected type integer in
>   column 1. CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_analysis1_data(date,date)
>   line 38 at RETURN QUERY
>   ********** Error **********

for the code of `postgresql` procedure:-

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_analysis1_data( IN date, IN date) RETURNS TABLE ( loc_no integer, loc_d_share double precision, loc_id_share double precision, loc_id_share_per double precision, loc_a integer, loc_m integer, loc_l integer, loc_oneway integer, loc_round integer, loc_replacement integer, loc_oncall integer, loc_avg_idshare double precision, out_no integer, out_d_share double precision, out_id_share double precision, out_id_share_per double precision, out_a integer, out_m integer, out_l integer, out_oneway integer, out_round integer, out_replacement integer, out_oncall integer, out_avg_idshare double precision ) AS $ BODY $ 
DECLARE in_from_date ALIAS FOR $1;
in_to_date ALIAS FOR $2;
loc_no integer;
loc_d_share double precision;
loc_id_share double precision;
loc_id_share_per double precision;
loc_a integer;
loc_m integer;
loc_l integer;
loc_oneway integer;
loc_round integer;
loc_replacement integer;
loc_oncall integer;
loc_avg_idshare double precision;
out_no integer;
out_d_share double precision;
out_id_share double precision;
out_id_share_per double precision;
out_a integer;
out_m integer;
out_l integer;
out_oneway integer;
out_round integer;
out_replacement integer;
out_oncall integer;
out_avg_idshare double precision;
BEGIN
   RETURN Query 
   SELECT
( ( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         (
            is_outstation = FALSE 
         )
         and 
         (
            reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date 
         )
) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(SUM(driver_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(SUM(id_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round((SUM(id_share) / SUM(driver_share + id_share))*100), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'A' 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'M' 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'L' 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_round_trip = FALSE 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_round_trip = TRUE 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         trip_type = 'Replacement' 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         trip_type = 'OnCall' 
         AND is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(AVG(id_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = FALSE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(SUM(driver_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(SUM(id_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(((SUM(id_share) / SUM(driver_share + id_share))*100)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'A' 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'M' 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         car_type = 'L' 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_round_trip = FALSE 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_round_trip = TRUE 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         trip_type = 'Replacement' 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         count(*) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         trip_type = 'OnCall' 
         AND is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) 
      UNION
( 
      SELECT
         coalesce(round(AVG(id_share)), 0) 
      FROM
         bookings 
      WHERE
         is_outstation = TRUE 
         AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date) ) ;
END
$ BODY $ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100 ROWS 1000;



ALTER FUNCTION public.get_analysis1_data(date, date)   OWNER TO
 postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you see is going to be the first of many.  Your function indicates it wants to see a recordset come back that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_analysis1_data(IN date, IN date)
  RETURNS TABLE (
    loc_no integer, 
    loc_d_share double precision, 
    loc_id_share double precision, 
    loc_id_share_per double precision, 
    loc_a integer, 
    loc_m integer, 
    loc_l integer, 
    loc_oneway integer, 
    loc_round integer, 
    loc_replacement integer, 
    loc_oncall integer, 
    loc_avg_idshare double precision, 
    out_no integer, 
    out_d_share double precision, 
    out_id_share double precision, 
    out_id_share_per double precision, 
    out_a integer, 
    out_m integer, 
    out_l integer, 
    out_oneway integer, 
    out_round integer, 
    out_replacement integer, 
    out_oncall integer, 
    out_avg_idshare double precision) AS
```

But as far as I can tell, your query is only returning a single column back (mixed datatypes to boot).  What about the other 20+ fields?

The error itself almost doesn't matter -- your query is returning a double precision (probably because of this: `coalesce(round((SUM(id_share) /                                   SUM(driver_share + id_share)) * 100),`), but I don't think that's your real problem.  I think your problem is your query looks nothing like what the function is expecting.

If I had to guess, you want your query results to be horizonal (pivoted) rather than vertical -- in a series of union queries.

I'm not recommending this, but the way your function is built, it seems like you want to do this:

```
SELECT count(*)
INTO loc_m
FROM bookings
WHERE car_type = 'A'
AND is_outstation = FALSE
AND reporting_date BETWEEN in_from_date AND in_to_date;
```

(note the addition of the second line, `INTO`)

and then your final line of the query would read:

```
return query select ... loc_m, ...
```

But I think a single, pivot query might be better.